# How do I make the spaces in Java, run the program easily, and see the different colors for different sections of code to make it readable?

Tags: java, matlab

I've been watching and reading Java tutorials for several days and I still don't understand how to use it.

My professor says I have to have 4 spaces to the right when there's a bracket, and then 4 to the left when I close the bracket. When I use an online compiler it does this automatically but I'm not allowed to use online I have to use a desktop version. Does that mean I have to manually type loads of spaces every single time I open a bracket?

Is there not an application where I can type in the code and it automatically makes a few spaces to the right when I make a new bracket, and then moves it back to the left when I close the bracket? And where I just type the code and click on a green "run" button and it just runs the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an online Java formatter, like [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_java_formatter.htm), for small programs.

You can also use a real [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), like Intellij Idea or Netbeans.  IDE's are capable of formatting your code automatically, have loads of other coding benefits, and are freely available and easily installable on your computer.

**Further Reading**
[The 13 Best Java IDE's for 2021](https://www.guru99.com/best-java-ide.html)

Answer (score 0):

An IDE should do the trick, they usually have multiple plugins you can download to program according to your liking. Here is a site that helps you choose the your optimal Java IDE: https://hackr.io/blog/best-java-ides

> Java is one of the leading programming languages. Widely employed for
> developing robust and secure desktop apps, enterprise applications,
> mobile apps, and web applications.
>
> There is a multitude of free Java IDEs available for working with
> Java. While Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, and NetBeans are the big three of
> Java, there are numerous other IDEs for developing apps effectively
> using Java.
>
> and more at the above link!

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Integrated Development Environment (IDE). I suggest you to use Eclipse and download it at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/